# errorhandler in flask and nginx server

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am using the following errorhandler in my flask app

```
@app.errorhandler(413)
def error413(e):
    return render_template('error413.html'), 413
```

which shows an error page if error 413 happens (filesize too large). This works fine on my localhost, but on the server I get the nginx 413 error page instead.

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

Is there anything which is different between nginx server and localhost regarding error handling? 
I use gunicorn together with nginx...
thanks
carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, nginx catch HTTP error codes. It is a good thing, for security purposes.

It is possible to disable this behaviour, you can set `uwsgi_intercept_errors off`.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_intercept_errors

You can use custom static error pages, served by nginx. Example:

```
error_page 413 /custom_413.html;

location = /custom_413.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
}
```

Just set it to all error codes you want to handle.